# Get value of textfield after selecting option

Tags: javascript, html

i have this code which changes the input type of my textfield between email and text.

```
 <div id ="info_input" class="container">
      <form class="col s12">
          <div  class="row">
             <div  style="padding-top: 15px;padding-left: 50px" class="col s6 l4">
             <select class = "source">
                <option value="" disabled>Choose your option</option>
                <option value="select_id">ID</option>
                <option value="select_email">EMAIL</option>
              </select>
              <label>INPUT SELECTION</label>
          </div>

        <div class="input-field col s6 l5">
            <div id = "source_input_field_id_div">
                   <input id="source_input_field" type="text" class="validate" required>
                    <label for="source_input_field_id">ID</label>
            </div>

            <div id = "source_input_field_email_div">
                     <input id="source_input_field" type="email" class="validate" required>
                      <label for="source_input_field_email">Email</label>
             </div>
         </div>

         <div style="padding-top: 15px">
            <a onclick="getInfo()"; class="waves-effect waves-light btn">button</a>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

then my type-change code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //hide email form
    $("#source_input_field_email_div").hide();


    $("select.source").change(function(){
        var selectedSource = $(".source option:selected").val();
        if(String(selectedSource) == 'select_id'){
          $("#source_input_field_id_div").show();
          $("#source_input_field_email_div").hide();

        }
        else{
          $("#source_input_field_id_div").hide();
          $("#source_input_field_email_div").show();
        }



    });
});
</script>
```

I have a button when clicked must log which field value must be logged

```
 function getInfo(){
    var input_value = document.getElementById('source_input_field').value;
    console.log(input_value);
  }
```

the only value the button gets is with the ID tag. any turn around for this?

EDIT:

change my get Info to get the right text. chamged the id of both textfield

```
 if(String(selectedSource) == 'select_id'){
        input_value = document.getElementById('source_input_field_id').value;

        }
        else{
          input_value = document.getElementById('source_input_field_email').value;
        }
        console.log(input_value);
```

Comment: You have duplicate IDs in your HTML.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes you are right. thanks!